# Python function with double condition

Tags: python, assertion

I'd like to create a function that returns the elements of a list on odd positions or the negative elements of a list.

My solution works with the first assertion, but the second generates an AssertionError, because returns [-1, -2, 1] instead of [-1, -2]. Any suggestions?

```
def solution(input):
  output = []
  for item in input: 
    if item < 0:
        output.append(item)
    elif not item % 2 == 0:
        output.append(item)
  return output

assert solution([0,1,2,3,4,5]) == [1,3,5]
assert solution([1,-1,2,-2]) == [-1,-2]
```

Comment: why would it not be `[-1,-2,1]` ? 1 is odd ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley It's suppose to get numbers that are either in odd positions or negative, so `[-1, -2, 1]` is incorrect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the numbers on odd positions, but your `%` check is checking the actual values in the list rather than their positions.

Try using `enumerate` to get the index alongside the value as you iterate through the list:

```
def solution(input):
  output = []
  for ix, item in enumerate(input): 
    if item < 0 or ix % 2 != 0:
        output.append(item)
  return output
```

Answer (score 0):

Also for completeness purpose you may want to consider adding this to your already existing code:

```
    if any(i < 0 for i in output):
            return [i for i in output if i < 0]
```

, since it tests if a negative exists and return only those if so. The answer by HumphreyTriscuit is, however, the better solution from my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

One line to define solution function:

```
def solution(input):
    return [input[pos] for pos in range(len(input)) if not pos %2 == 0 or input[pos] < 0]

print solution([0,1,2,3,4,5,7])
print solution([1,-1,2,-2, -3])
```